# SQL Remove a row of data based on 2 date fields in previous row

Tags: sql, sql-delete, row-number

I've searched through stack overflow but I can't find exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.  I have some aggregated data that looks like the below (rn is a field populated using Row Number):

[image]

What I would like to do is write a query that would delete the 2nd row of data since the StartDate is greater than the previous rows startdate AND the EndDate is less than the previous rows EndDate.  So I would be left with 2 records for this dataset, the 1st and 3rd row as they're startdate and enddate are not within the same timeframe as the previous row.  Also this should be a dynamic delete and not something such as "DELETE * from table where rn = 2".

Any help is greatly appreciated and please let me know if more information is required.  Thanks guys!

Comment: What level do you want the solution to be executed at? org_id? user_id? profession? Combination of 2 or more?

Comment: Hey Mithrandir, Shawnt00's answer worked perfectly and I marked it as the answer.  Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delete from T
where exists (
    select 1 from T t2
    where   t2.org_id = T.org_id and t2.user_id = T.user_id
        and t2.startdate < T.startdate and t2.enddate > T.enddate)
);
```

Comment: That got it Shawnt00!!  Thanks a million for the super quick and easy to understand resolution!!  I love Stack Overflow!!